# oracleで1度問い合わせたSQLが2回目からは結果を返して来ません

Tags: sql, oracle

oracleデータベースで,1度目に問い合わせた場合は数秒で結果が返ってくるのですが、直後に全く同じSQLで問い合わせを行うと、途端に結果を返してくれなくなってしまいます。

SQLや実行計画を記載出来ないのが申し訳ないのですが、以下のような状況です。

- 10個程度テーブルを外部結合
- 多いテーブルでは70万レコード、他は数万レコード
- 各テーブルはanalyzeを施した直後
- 実行計画のコストは10000ほど

調べたところ`[alter system flush shared_pool]`で実行計画のキャッシュを消せるとあったため試したところ、その直後はまた結果がすぐ返ってきました。

現在は開発段階なので都度flushしているのですが、それ以外の方法で改善する方法はありませんでしょうか。やはりSQLチューニングが必要でしょうか。

環境については以下のような状況です。

- 仮想マシン上のWindowsサーバ
- Oracle 11.2
- 仮装マシンメモリ8GB
- その他詳しい設定などは不明(調べ方/注意点がわかりません)

拙い質問ですがよろしくお願い致します.

---

**追記**
書き忘れておりましたが、仮想マシンのタスクマネージャを見ていると1回目の結果が返ってくる際にはCPU使用率が上がったりするのですが、2回目以降はCPU使用率が動いているように見えませんでした。
(これは推測が多分に含まれますが。)

なお、EnterpriseManagerを監視する権限はありません。(状況を都度聞きに行くことは可能です。)

---

**追記2**
1回目の問い合わせと2回目の問い合わせのSQLトレースを取得したところ、
以下のような状態でした。
これは2回目にFetchでつまづいてしまっているということでしょうか。

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
Parse        1      0.57       0.58          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        1      1.18       1.20          0     249222          0          61
total        3      1.76       1.78          0     249222          0          61
```

2回目の問い合わせ後のトレース

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
Parse        2      1.20       1.20          0          0          0           0
Execute      2      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        2   2723.88    3392.82   45574362  237788264          0           0
total        6   2725.08    3394.02   45574362  237788264          0           0
```

Comment: 2回目は時間がかかるにせよ最終的には結果を返してくれるのですか？返してくれる場合はどれくらい時間がかかりますか？（時々で違う場合でも情報として大体の時間など）。

Comment: 30分以上は待ったことがないのですが,それで結果が返って来たことはありません.

Comment: どの程度のサイズの結果が返ってくるか（レコード長もたいしたことない 1件でも起きるのか、あまり件数は関係なく、同じ様な結合であれば2回目はかならずそうなるなど）もあると良いと思います。それと 2回目はディスクアクセスがどうなっているか（大量にディスク読み書きしていないか）も個人的に気になります。

Comment: 返ってきたことがないのであれば、念のためV$LOCK表などでなにかロックが起きていないか見てみてもいいかもしれません。

Comment: メインのテーブルがまだ50件ほどで,最終的な結果もそれ以下の件数です.  
絞り込み条件を追加しても状況は変わらなかったように思います.  
(ちょっと記憶が曖昧ですみません.)  
ディスクアクセス/V$LOCKはちゃんと見ていなかったので確認してみます.

Answer (score 1):

別の回答にもありましたが、SQLトレースの取得して、PARSE, EXECUTE, FETCHのどのフェーズで時間を要しているか確認すべきでしょう。
なお、テーブルの結合数が多い、２回目のみ発生といった問題の状況から、ソフトパースに（想定外の）時間を要していることが疑われます。
Oracle Databaseの不具合の可能性も含めて調査を進めるべきでしょう。また、可能であれば最新のPatch Setで問題が回避できないか確認してください。

Answer (score 0):

カーディナリティフィードバックを無効にしてください